# How to run program in background in android?

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
package com.powergroupbd.timer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TimerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    EditText minute, seconds;
    Button fire;
    String min, sec;
    TextView Remain;
    MyCount timercount;
    Intent serviceIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        initializer();
        fire.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void initializer() {

        minute = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMinute);
        seconds = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSeconds);
        fire = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bFireTimer);
        Remain = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRemain);
        serviceIntent = new Intent(TimerActivity.this, MyService.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.bFireTimer:

            min = minute.getText().toString();
            sec = seconds.getText().toString();
            int MIN = Integer.parseInt(min);
            int SEC = Integer.parseInt(sec);
            long TIME = (MIN * 60) + SEC;
            timercount = new MyCount(TIME * 1000, 1000);
            timercount.start();

            startService(serviceIntent);

            break;
        }

    }

    public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

        public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // some script here

            Remain.setText("0:0");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            // some script here
            int remseconds = (int) millisUntilFinished / 1000;
            int remminuts = remseconds / 60;
            remseconds = remseconds % 60;
            remminuts = remminuts % 60;
            Remain.setText(String.format("%d : %02d", remminuts, remseconds));

            // Remain.setText(""+millisUntilFinished);

        }
    }

}
```

I am putting some numeric value in an edittext and do countdown from that value to zero. But when I restart this app it starts from the begining and have to put those values again. But I want to do that countdown in background when I am not in that application. I used service here and My service class code is here:

```
package com.powergroupbd.timer;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MyService extends Service {



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

But nothing heppens, what to do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there's no way to run in background constantly. Background services are subject to termination by the OS when memory runs low. Try alarms (as in `AlarmManager`) in conjuction with persistent variables (e. g. stored in `Preferences`).

Comment: This is technically true, but kind of misleading.  You can run a back-round with an extremely high priority.  Think the Pandora or music player app.  It has a persistent back-round process that continues to play music.  The OS CAN kill it if it needs to, but this is EXTREMELY unlikely as it has the same priority of the apps active process.

Comment: If all you want to do is count backwards, there's no reason to force your app to keep running. Just use the `AlarmManager` as @Seva suggests above. It's much more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds Like you want the count to continue in the background, this can be accomplished with a background process.  I'd assume there is a better way within the android api but

[Simialar stackoverflow question on services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742988/what-happens-if-i-startservice-from-oncreate-in-activity-finish-the-activity/7781308#7781308)

If you simply want the counter to restart at the point you left off, you need to manage your lifecycle.  Save the number on exit and reload on a startup.

[Process Lifecycle documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle)